# Superbible 6th edition undefined platform error

Tags: opengl, codeblocks, sample

I just started off with learning openGL from the superbible(6th edition) with code::blocks.
But when i try to run the first sample code i get an undefined platform error from the sb6.h file.

sample code:

```
#include "sb6.h"

// Derive my_application from sb6::application
class my_application : public sb6::application
{
public:
    // Our rendering function
    void render(double currentTime)
    {
        // Simply clear the window with red
        static const GLfloat red[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);
    }
};

// Our one and only instance of DECLARE_MAIN
DECLARE_MAIN(my_application);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you post the actual error you're getting?

Comment: What platform are you on and what compiler are you using?

Comment: Oh yea my pc is running on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: And im using GNU GCC Compiler, that is the error (error: #error Undefined patform!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because that [header file](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/blob/60ccda3dfa612d6f43fa5371e5846aec41b9ee40/include/sb6.h) expects one of `_WIN32`, `_LINUX` or `__APPLE__` to be defined.  Usually these are defined by the compiler or one of the platform's headers.  You could also pass them to your compiler, e.g. `-D_LINUX` or define it in your source file before you include their header, e.g.:

```
#ifndef _LINUX
#define _LINUX
#endif
```

`gcc` actually defines `__linux`, but this is not what the header file is checking for.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are not using the CMake provided along with the projects. The CMake build process automatically adds -D_LINUX, on Linux systems when detected.  Refer to the file CMakeLists.txt (https://github.com/prabindh/sb6code/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) around line 135. If you are not using CMake, you will need to do a similar addition to the build flags.

Answer (score 0):

The end of sb6.h has a set of preprocessor defines for various operating systems, and the '#elif  defined _LINUX || defined **APPLE**' is not reached for some reason. I commented out from '#if defined _WIN32' to '**APPLE**' and from '#else' to second last '#endif'. Between those commented out sections is the #define DECLARE_MAIN(a)' that is needed.

Good luck getting the rest of the programs to compile.